# How you could you change the surface area formula for a cylinder to calculate the curved surface area of the half pipe?

Tags: 3d, geometry

[image]

Skateboarders use half pipes for doing tricks. A half-pipe is a half cylinder. Explain how you could manipulate the surface area formula for a cylinder to calculate the curved surface area of the half pipe. To the nearest square metre, what is the curved surface area of the half pipe if it is 7 m long?

I think that i have a pretty good understanding of surface area and composite objects but I'm stumped on this question because I don't know if I'm seeing it the right way. In the question it states that a  half pipe is a half cylinder, so when you try to solve the problem is it as easy as dividing the surface area of the cylinder in half? The 'curved' area is the cause of my confusion.

Radius = 2.5 m Length = 7 m
Half cylinder formula- ½ (pi r^2) + (2 pi R h)
Pi x 2.5^2 + 2 x pi x 2.5 x 7

129.5906969 x .5 = 64.795348 m^2
The surface area of the half pipe is 65 m^2.

Answer (score 1):

You're not *too* far off. But let's take a closer look at the formula for the surface area of a cylinder.
$$A=2 \pi rh+2 \pi r^2$$
What does each part refer to? You will probably recognize $\pi r^2$ as the formula for the area of a circle with radius $r$. The term $2 \pi r^2$ is here because a cylinder is bounded on either side by a circle. Since we do not want our half pipe to be bounded (the question asks for "the curved surface area"), we can drop this term altogether.

We are left with $A=2 \pi rh$, which you can think of as the area of a cylinder with the ends punched out. To get our half pipe, we simply cut this in half along its height, so our final area is $A=\pi rh$. You can now plug in your values to get the answer.

Comment: Cylinder surface area = 2 pi r h + 2 pi r^2
( Half cylinder is / 2)
Radius- 2.5 m 7 m long 
2 Pi x 2.5^2 + 2 x pi x 2.5 x 7
149.226 m^2 – 39.26990817 
= 109.9557429 / 2
= 54.97787147

A = pi x r x h (pi x 2.5 x 7)
54.97787144
The curved surface area of the half pipe is 55 m^2.
So this would be the correct way to solve a problem such as this one, correct?

Comment: The way you've written it out is pretty confusing, but I think you have the right idea, and your answer is correct. It looks like you went through the whole process numerically (calculating the area of the cylinder, subtracting the area of the circular caps, and finally cutting in half), got your answer of $54.978 \text{ m}^2$, and then used $A=\pi r h$ to check your work. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for your help!